# How to wrap every exported comopnent with HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, es6-modules

I need to add to **ALL** of my React function components the possibility to add `[data-test-id]` attribute for testing purposes. To achieve that I created `withTestId()` HOC which adds optional prop `testId` to wrapped component and when it's defined it adds `[data-test-id]` to final HTML.

So when I define component like:

```js
<ExampleComponent testId="example" />
```

it returns:

```html
<div data-test-id="example" />
```

The only problem I have is to apply it to every component without the necessity to wrap it individually in every component. So instead of writing code like:

```js
function ExampleComponent() { ... }

export default withTestId(ExampleComponent)
```

I would like to wrap all of my exports in my `index.ts` file, which right now looks like this:

```js
export { default as ExampleComponent } from "./ExampleComponent";
export { default as ExampleComponent2 } from "./ExampleComponent2";
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure an HoC is the way to go if you want it everywhere.

Comment: So what else would you recommend?

Comment: Data attributes are already valid props by default, why not just `<TestComponent data-test-id="123" />` and make sure you apply the unknown props to the root element of each component with `<div {...props}>`? No need for an HoC anymore and it works with anything you'd want to apply to a component. Though this is a [risky pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43532684/1218980) depending on how well you manage the props already. I personally use it a lot, but I also filter out any unneeded props at all the different levels of the component tree.

Comment: But it's a good question and maybe there's a way I just don't know about.

Comment: That's a good point that `data` attributes are valid by default but my current eslint config [doesn't allow](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md) to use props spreading and I'm not sure if it's a good idea to disable it.

Comment: If you have props types validation, you'll get warnings or errors when unintentional extra props are passed down, so the `jsx-props-no-spreading` can be disabled safely. It could still impact maintainability a little, but it would decrease a lot the boilerplate, the tree depth (which each HoC increases), improves the tree-shaking (where an index exporting everything impairs tree-shaking a lot), and overall less complexity since spreading is a common pattern versus export code generation etc.

Comment: I think that I will use this approach. You're right that it's safe to use when I have types validation. Of course, this rule has it's advantages and disadvantages but I'm beginning to think that there are more positive aspects of disabling it than leaving it turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two ways of doing this; One dynamic way, making the user-code of your library a bit more convoluted. with you being able to change the implementation easily and another one with a bit more boilerplate code, keeping the user-code as it is.

I haven't tested their behavior regarding tree-shaking when bundling the code.

### Using destructing in user-code

This allows to add / remove things from your main component export file without having to worry about additional boilerplate in your library. The higher-order-component can be switched on/off easily. One caveat: The user code needs to use destructuring to retrieve the components.

Your new `index.ts` file would look like this, while I've called your previous `index.ts` file `components.ts` in the same directory:

```js
import * as RegularComponents from "./components";
import withTestId from "./with-test-id";

const WithTestIdComponents = Object
  .keys(RegularComponents)
  .reduce((testIdComps, key) => {
    return {
      ...testIdComps,
      [key]: withTestId(RegularComponents[key])
    };
  }, {});

export default WithTestIdComponents;
```

To use it in your application code:

```
import MyComponents from "./components/tested";
const { Component1, Component2, Component3, Component4 } = MyComponents;
```

This uses the `default` export to make it look like you have all components in one place, but since you cannot destructure exports directly, you need this second step to get the correct components out of it.

### Add boilerplate to the export file

Since there is an `index.ts` file with all the components exported in the library, one could import/rename each component and re-export them with `withTestId` and their name:

```
import withTestId from "./with-test-id";
import { default as TmpComponent1 } from "./component1";
import { default as TmpComponent2 } from "./component2";
import { default as TmpComponent3 } from "./component3";
import { default as TmpComponent4 } from "./component4";
export const Component1 = withTestId(TmpComponent1);
export const Component2 = withTestId(TmpComponent2);
export const Component3 = withTestId(TmpComponent3);
export const Component4 = withTestId(TmpComponent4);
```

This way, imports can be used as before:

```
import {
  Component1,
  Component2,
  Component3,
  Component4
} from "./components";
```

I'd argue that using `index` files already is some kind of boilerplate and this approach adds to it. Since the user code does not need any changes, I'd favor this approach.

In one of our projects, we have used a custom [takeoff](https://github.com/entwicklerstube/takeoff) script to create this kind of boilerplate for us, whenever we generate a new component.

### Examples

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-exported-components-2j68n) to see both approaches.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also think that the second approach would be a better option. I will try to write some script that will generate these `index.ts` files for me - that sounds like the best solution. When you were using your `takeoff` script you had to run it manually right? Or did you have some kind of a watcher that was running the script when a new component arrived?

Comment: I used takeoff to generate the component and the exports at the same time. The CLI can call your script and generate multiple files or change some index.ts file, etc.